Error running EMF Ecore project as an Eclipse application on ARM/M3 architecture
I recently moved from a windows machine to a MacbookPro M3 and I'm trying to run an EMF Ecore project I had on my previous machine as an Eclipse application on this new machine.
I downloaded the 2024-03 version of Eclipse Modeling Tools for ARM architectures, installed the JDK 21 and setup the build path. However when I try to run the project has an eclipse application I got this error:
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "org.eclipse.ui.ide.application" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication".
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:242)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:235)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:987)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:255)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:65)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:143)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:109)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:439)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:271)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:651)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:588)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1459)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1432)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3549)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3754)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2930)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:233)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench (991).
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:134)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:620)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:348)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:414)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:520)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:434)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:814)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:761)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1057)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:387)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:639)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:498)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:528)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:620)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:348)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:414)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:520)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:434)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:174)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:643)
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.initDependencyManagers(AbstractComponentManager.java:1027)
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.collectDependencies(AbstractComponentManager.java:1057)
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getServiceInternal(SingleComponentManager.java:955)
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getService(SingleComponentManager.java:920)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceFactoryUse$1.run(ServiceFactoryUse.java:226)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceFactoryUse.factoryGetService(ServiceFactoryUse.java:223)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceFactoryUse.getService(ServiceFactoryUse.java:118)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceConsumer$2.getService(ServiceConsumer.java:48)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getService(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:580)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.getService(ServiceRegistry.java:548)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.getService(BundleContextImpl.java:672)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.debug.FrameworkDebugOptions.addingService(FrameworkDebugOptions.java:542)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.debug.FrameworkDebugOptions.addingService(FrameworkDebugOptions.java:1)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:947)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:1)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:257)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:230)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:907)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:133)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:956)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:890)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:145)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:274)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:501)
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$3.register(AbstractComponentManager.java:929)
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$3.register(AbstractComponentManager.java:915)
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.RegistrationManager.changeRegistration(RegistrationManager.java:133)
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.registerService(AbstractComponentManager.java:984)
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:752)
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.enableInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:674)
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.enable(AbstractComponentManager.java:437)
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ConfigurableComponentHolder.enableComponents(ConfigurableComponentHolder.java:671)
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.initialEnable(BundleComponentActivator.java:310)
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.loadComponents(Activator.java:613)
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.access$200(Activator.java:75)
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator$ScrExtension.start(Activator.java:480)
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.AbstractExtender.createExtension(AbstractExtender.java:196)
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.AbstractExtender.modifiedBundle(AbstractExtender.java:169)
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.AbstractExtender.addingBundle(AbstractExtender.java:139)
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.AbstractExtender.addingBundle(AbstractExtender.java:49)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:477)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:1)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:257)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:230)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:452)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:972)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:235)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:126)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:229)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:531)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:516)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:2073)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:143)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2064)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2004)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1967)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1883)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:341)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error starting module. osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.131.100.v20240221-2107"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.ui.workbench"; singleton:="true" \[id=991\]
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:648)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:498)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:528)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
... 88 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/SWTError
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3549)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3754)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2442)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:815)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:761)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1057)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:387)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:639)
... 91 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError cannot be found by org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.131.100.v20240221-2107
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.generateException(BundleLoader.java:562)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:557)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:434)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:174)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)

Moreover, I can see these errors from the IDE:
- The type org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type org.eclipse.jface.action.Action
    
- The type org.eclipse.swt.events.HelpListener cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type org.eclipse.jface.action.Action

Of course the application was running fine on my windows machine, so I guess it's something related to the different OS. Any suggestion?
Thank you

SWT is OS and processor architecture specific, you need to make sure you are using the macOS ARM version of SWT.

Do you know how can I check it? I know Ecore projects have their own way of managing dependencies

There should be a org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.aarch64_xxx plugin in a build for macOS aarch 64, rather than org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.win32.x86_64 for Windows. I don't know how eCore is built. For a RCP using tycho the tycho target-platform-configuration controls the the target platforms.
